# React.js msal ad authentication directly without any login button

Tags: reactjs, authentication, azure-ad-msal

Has anyone of you seen any example or documents how to do AD Authentication in React.js Application that does not use any Login buttons when User is all ready Authenticated?

I have look many Authentication samples like Microsoft's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react has but everyone of them has a Sign-in and Sing-out Buttons not automatic Authentication and redirect if User has all ready logged in and Authenticated. I mean something like SSO style AD Authentication that is usually wanted to Customer's Web Applications. I use MSAL packages.

Any help valued.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localStorage or cookies to store the localStorage or cookies to store the token, and when you reload the application then you can check if the token is valid and available in localStorage or Cookies, if it is then redirect the user to the home page otherwise redirect the user to the login page.

In the MSAL browser, acquireTokenSilent get's refresh token on every call to the token end point. The very first refresh token has a duration of 1 hour. Subsequent refresh tokens all have reduced (the remaining) expiry time.